# Create hyperlink in DIalogue Box using Applescript ?

Tags: hyperlink, applescript, dialog

```
display dialog "Sample 

    i . Go to Google [http://wwww.google.com']

. .. … ….. …….. …………. ……..…………." buttons {"Proceed"} default button 1
```

How to create an actual working hyperlink inside of a dialogue box using Applescript ?

Comment: Can't be done. A dialog box only accepts text.

Comment: That isn't something that the scripting system offers. But one can select that URL in the dialog box text and CTRL-Click it to "Open URL".